# Cannot get .NET Core NUnit test project's reference to my production class library to work

Tags: c#, nunit, .net-core, nunit-3.0

I have the simplest solution setup possible for a production assembly and a unit tests assembly. First, here is the relevant configuration:

```
Common.sln
global.json
-- src
---- Common
------ project.json
-- test
---- UnitTests
------ project.json
```

`global.json`:

```
{
  "projects: [ "src", "test" ]
}
```

`Common\project.json`:

```
{
  "name": "<redacted>",
  "version": "2.0.0-*",
  "description": "<redacted>",
  "copyright": "© 2016 <redacted>",
  "title": "<redacted>",
  "authors": [ "<redacted>" ],
  "language": "en-US",
  "buildOptions": {
    "platform": "anycpu",
    "xmlDoc": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

`UnitTests\project.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0-*",
  "testRunner": "nunit",
  "dependencies": {
    "Common": {
      "target": "project"
    },
    "NUnit": "3.4.1",
    "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "netcoreapp1.0",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.0.1-*",
          "type": "platform"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I compile, I get these errors in the Error List:

```
Error   NU1002  The dependency Common  does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0. UnitTests   <redacted>\UnitTests\project.json   5   
Error           The given key was not present in the dictionary.    UnitTests       1
```

What's going on here? I've followed every tutorial I can find to try and set these projects up, but none of them work. Perhaps things have changed in .NET Core land since the tutorials were created? What do I need to change to get the `UnitTests` project to recognize my `Common` project?

Two other smaller concerns:

1. I'm running Windows 7 SP1. Does that pose a problem with the `portable-net45+win8` import?
2. There is a newer version of `Microsoft.NETCore.App`: 1.0.1. Originally, `project.json` was referencing version 1.0.0, so I changed it. However, in Solution Explorer, I still see 1.0.0.

References:

http://www.alteridem.net/2016/06/18/nunit-3-testing-net-core-rc2/

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? I am guessing yes based on the SLN file. Also, does your global.json include each of the projects? Can you edit your answer and add the global.json?

Comment: Yep, VS 2015 Update 3, fully patched.

Comment: I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Try removing the buildoptions

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems the Visual Studio tooling is so bad in its current state that the actual errors I receive from a NuGet restore and compile keep changing. I can't get any kind of consistent behavior.

Comment: Removing `buildoptions` appears to have had no effect.

Comment: It seems like this approach won't actually work because NUnit does not yet support targeting .NET Standard. I'll leave the question here so others can have a point of reference if they run into the same issue. It seems like the recommendation still is to use NUnitLite with a console application wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that nearly everything I was seeing was simply tooling issues. I hope Microsoft addresses this soon; it's very confusing to see stale error messages in the Error List. Everything works fine when running `dotnet build` and `dotnet test` from the command line.

I am now targeting `netstandard1.5` because, from what I'm able to gather, it has [parity with .NET Framework 4.6.2](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms), which I was targeting prior to this work.

Here are the final versions of `project.json`:

`Common\project.json`:

```
{
  "name": "<redacted>",
  "version": "2.0.0-*",
  "description": "<redacted>",
  "copyright": "<redacted>",
  "title": "<redacted>",
  "authors": [ "<redacted>" ],
  "language": "en-US",
  "packOptions": {
    "tags": [
      "GM",
      "UAS",
      "Common"
    ],
    "iconUrl": "<redacted>",
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "<redacted>"
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "xmlDoc": true,
    "compile": {
      "include": [
        "GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs"
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {}
  }
}
```

`UnitTests\project.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "testRunner": "nunit",
  "dependencies": {
    "NUnit": "3.4.0",
    "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-2",
    "Common": {
      "target": "project"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8",
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.0.0-*",
          "type": "platform"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```